# " ' " removes previous field data

Tags: php, mysql

I'm missing something here.  You can see that I get info from a text file that's comma separated.  The insert works fine until it reaches a point where the 2nd variable `$player_id` is empty.  If it's empty, then the `$town_name` throws an error.  If it's not empty, and the `$town_name` has a string with `.` or other characters, it fails and for some reason, it acts as if `$player_id` is empty!

**What am I missing!?**

Terribly sorry.  Here is the response I get from the code as-is:

> 75767, , 1.+Harlekus%27s+city, 519, 851, 5, 414
>
> Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ' '1.+Harlekus%27s+city', 519, 851, 5, 414 )' at line 2

And here is the code I get when I remove "'".mysql_real_escape_string($town_name)."'" and just replace it with mysql_real_escape_string($town_name):

> 80290, 2299128, Spencer, 414, 371, 0, 3633  Invalid query: Unknown
>   column 'Spencer' in 'field list'

```
mysql_select_db($database_connI, $connI);
ini_set("memory_limit","100M");
mysql_query("towns");
$datafile = gzfile('towns.txt.gz');
if(!is_array($datafile)) die("File could not be opened");

foreach($datafile as $datum){
    list($town_id, $player_id, $town_name, $island_x, $island_y, $number_on_island, $points) = explode(',', $datum);

if(is_null($player_id)) {
    $player_id = 0;
}


    $protectedInsert = sprintf('INSERT INTO towns (`town_id`,`player_id`,`town_name`,`island_x`,`island_y`,`number_on_island`,`town_points`)
        VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',
        $town_id, 
            $player_id,
            "'".mysql_real_escape_string($town_name)."'",
            $island_x,
            $island_y, 
            $number_on_island, 
            $points);

    $freed = mysql_query("TRUNCATE towns");// empty the table before inserting the new data
    $result = mysql_query($protectedInsert);//Re-fill the table with updated data
    if (!$result) {
    print"$town_id, $player_id, $town_name, $island_x, $island_y, $number_on_island, $points <br><br>";
        print"$INSERT <br><br>";
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
print "The database has been updated";
mysql_close($dbh);
```

Comment: I'm having a super hard time trying to understand your problem statement. If you could provide a sample input/output, what breaks and what you want happening...

Comment: What did return `mysql_error()`?

Comment: Sorry about that.  I updated the post with example output

Answer (score 0):

I would check `strlen($player_id)` vs `is_null` as $player_id is defined, but it may have a whitespace or just no value, that doesn't mean it is NULL.

This might be your problem.

Comment: That probably is a better way to do it, and I've changed it now.  Thanks, but doesn't solve issue.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider to use fgecsv (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fgetcsv.php)